# UCUM code for ratios

Tags: units-of-measurement, ucum

UCUM has a code for percentages, but seemingly none for ratios.

Typically, how would a ratio be encoded as a UCUM code (e.g. units for a "Immature reticulocyte fraction" lab result?)

Answer (score 0):

A fraction is just a number. It doesn't need a unit. A percent is just the same as 0.01.

On the other hand, a ratio (e.g. 5/7) is a way to write quantities with numerator and denominator, it's not really an issue of units.